# Apache2 .htaccess redirect to https not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ubuntu, mod-rewrite, https

I realize this is a question that was answered a lot but the other solutions are not working for me for some reason. I am trying to rewrite http as https but I am still getting 'Bad Request' when I try to browse my website using http.

Here is the code in my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

I have AllowOverride All in the VirtualHost config and I made sure mod_rewrite is enabled.

Any help is appreciated. Let me know if you need more information.

Edit:

Here is my complete .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RemoveHandler .html .htm
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .htm .html
```

POSSIBLE Solution:
I was using Apache 2.2. This may be a bug with the older version of Apache. I am going to update and I will post again when I know more.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should be sure of enable `mod_rewrite` and `ssl` on your apache, by this codes

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
sudo a2enmod ssl
```

and then restart your apache

```
 sudo service apache2 restart
```

now follow this steps

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf
```

and add this codes

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName my.site.com
    ServerAlias my.site.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/SITE-PATH
    <Directory /var/www/SITE-PATH>
        AllowOverride All
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from All
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/project_error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/project_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

then go to your website directory `/var/www/SITE-PATH` and add this code to your `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

and for your ssl credit on path `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default-ssl.conf`
you should have something like this

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost _default_:443>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerAdmin admin@example.com
        ServerName my.site.com #important
        ServerAlias my.site.com #important
        DocumentRoot /var/www/SITE-PATH #important
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.crt #important
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.key #important
        SSLCertificateFile  /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
        <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </FilesMatch>
        <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </Directory>
        BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
                nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
                downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
        BrowserMatch "MSIE [17-9]" ssl-unclean-shutdown
    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

if you go all steps right, you should have this at end

`http://my.site.com` => redirect to => `https://my.site.com`

EDIT:
for more detail on SSL please follow [How To Create a SSL Certificate on Apache for Ubuntu 14.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-ssl-certificate-on-apache-for-ubuntu-14-04) and [this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/550310)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm still getting '400 Bad Request' though.

Comment: @CoryPuckett what's your system? you mean when you open website by https, you get 400. or on redirect to https you get 400??

Comment: I'm running Ubuntu 14.04. If I open my site using "https:// my.site.com" it works fine. Only when I try "http:// my.site.com" do I get the '400 Bad Request'

Comment: @CoryPuckett and could you please add all your htaccess?

Comment: I have added my .htaccess to the original post.

Comment: @CoryPuckett one more question, when you try "http://my.site.com/" does it redirect to https version and then get 400 error or it's get 400 error and still on http mode??

Comment: @CoryPuckett i add some help on my answer, please check them, and let me know if work or not

Comment: going to "my.site.com" right now just defaults to the http version with the 400 error. I have used a walkthrough with almost the exact same steps to get my ssl cert.

Comment: Also, I looked into the post you mentioned that talked about ports. I tried forwarding all request from port 80 to 443 and I still get the same result. In fact, on the 400 error screen it mentions that the request was on port 443.

Comment: @CoryPuckett NO, it's not need to forward all request to port 443. i try this on opencart and wordpress and symfony. and work fine.let me add more detail of my codes

Answer (score 0):

Try: 
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
 RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I just tried it and I'm still getting 'Bad Request'