# php url rewrite remove ?= from url

Tags: php

I'm using the following htaccess code.

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^Profile/([0-9]+)/?$ ViewProfile.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

This is the url
http://localhost/ConnectMyProfile/ViewProfile.php?id=CMP26944

I need to convert this url to http://localhost/ConnectMyProfile/ViewProfile/CMP26944

For that i used  this code (RewriteRule ^Profile/([0-9]+)/?$ ViewProfile.php?id=$1 [NC,L]).

It's not working.Please help me to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for start mod-rewire start from the your domain. then on localhost if you want your mod_rewrite work you should pass it to your project address,

before all above thing, you should check your mode_Rewire be enable
redirect:
`http://localhost/ConnectMyProfile/ViewProfile.php?id=CMP26944` or 
 
`http://localhost/ConnectMyProfile/ViewProfile?id=CMP26944`
to 
`http://localhost/ConnectMyProfile/ViewProfile/CMP26944`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /ConnectMyProfile/


# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /ViewProfile\.php\?id=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ ViewProfile/%1? [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /ViewProfile\?id=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ ViewProfile/%1? [R=302,L]


# internally rewrites /ViewProfile/ABC123 to ViewProfile.php?id=ABC123
RewriteRule ^ViewProfile/([A-Z,0-9]+)$ ViewProfile.php?id=$1 [L,NC,QSA]

# PHP hiding rule
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: i'm getting same url (http://localhost/ConnectMyProfile/ViewProfile?id=CMP26944). Not changing

Comment: @user3667960, do you enable `mod_rewrite` on your system?

Comment: yes. (it's removing .php from the file. but the url is not changing)

Comment: @user3667960 yeah, sorry, i fix my answer and it works fine now

Comment: Hi bro.Sorry i'm not getting it.I'm clicking on this url http://localhost/ConnectMyProfile/ViewProfile?id=CMP26944.But this is not converting into http://localhost/ConnectMyProfile/ViewProfile/CMP26944.If i used http://localhost/ConnectMyProfile/ViewProfile.php?id=CMP26944 like this it is redirecting to http://localhost//ViewProfile.php

Comment: @user3667960 on your question you want to rediretc " http://localhost/ConnectMyProfile/ViewProfile.php?id=CMP26944 " to " http://localhost/ConnectMyProfile/ViewProfile/CMP26944 " ( url has ViewProfile.php ). am i wrong?

Comment: If i manually type this url (http://localhost/ConnectMyProfile/ViewProfile/CMP26944) i'm getting the page content. But if i clicked this link (localhost/ConnectMyProfile/ViewProfile?id=CMP26944) it is not converting to this one (http://localhost/ConnectMyProfile/ViewProfile/CMP26944)

Comment: when i click on this url localhost/ConnectMyProfile/ViewProfile?id=CMP26944 it will go to ViewProfile.php and there i get the id and display the details.But after clicking on that url it should be displayed as localhost/ConnectMyProfile/ViewProfile/CMP26944.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106192/discussion-between-shayanypn-and-user3667960).

Comment: hi bro. i uploaded the code in domain with same htaccess. it is taking to the followinr url - http://www.connectmyprofile.com/ConnectMyProfile/ViewProfile/CMP26944

Comment: @user3667960 does file ViewProfile.php exist on the directory? i mean does this htaccess code work on localhost and does not work on the server your?

Comment: yes.. it is working fine in localhost. but not working in server. ViewProfile.php file exists on server.

Comment: @user3667960 maybe mode_rewrite on enable on your server please follow [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35726774/3828573) for enabling apache mode_rewrite

Comment: need to change this ( RewriteBase /ConnectMyProfile/ ) in server ???

Comment: @user3667960 if you domain is "test.com/ConnectMyProfile/" , yes.

Comment: URL show as i want but on page showing Error: 500 Internal Server Error. how to resolve. I use above .htaccess code

Comment: Now i found if my url view.php?url=home  it will work if i have view.php?url=mapsko-casa-baella this will not work

Comment: i have url like abc-delhi-india etc not working